# Is it possible to open two separate connections on two different ports on netty server?

Tags: java, ssl, netty

It's a normal TCP/IP client server application. I want to open two different ports on the server. One port that will receive TLS connection and another for normal TCP/IP.
How can we implement this in netty server?

Answer (score 1):

Sure its possible...

Just create two different `ServerBootstrap` instances and configure these. At the end call `bind(...)` with different ports and thats it